# How do I NSString format this correctly?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5

Ok, it's a yellow bang error that says "Data argument not used by format string"

in the .h:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *UserFirstName;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *UserLastName;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *UserEmail;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *UserUser;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *UserPassword;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *UserConfirmPassword;

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *userFirstNameEntry;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *userLastNameEntry;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *emailEntry;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *userEntry;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *userPasswordEntry;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *userConfirmPasswordEntry;

- (IBAction)userCreate:(UIButton *)sender;

@end
```

And in the .m

```
- (IBAction)userCreate:(UIButton *)sender
{
    _userFirstNameEntry = UserFirstName.text;
    _userLastNameEntry = UserLastName.text;
    _emailEntry = UserEmail.text;
    _userEntry = UserUser.text;
    _userPasswordEntry = UserPassword.text;
    _userConfirmPasswordEntry = UserConfirmPassword.text;


NSString *postData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"FirstName=%@&LastName=%@&Email=%@&User=%@&Pass=%@&ConfirmPass", _userFirstNameEntry, _userLastNameEntry, _emailEntry, _userEntry, _userPasswordEntry, _userConfirmPasswordEntry];
```

I believe the error is with the NSString postData stringWithFormat, but I can't find any correct sources that lead me to a correct format, also I suppose the problem could me my method of setting the NSString's.

Comment: either remove `_userConfirmPasswordEntry` or add `=%@` at the end of &confirmPass in quotes

Comment: Are you using ARC?if so,you should `(nonatomic,weak)` for your `IBOutlet` and `(nonatomic,strong)` for you string property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `stringWithFormat:` has 5 placeholders (`%@`) but you pass 6 objects to it...

Comment: @WhiteHatPrince you're welcome. It happens.. you are so used to see your code that often you don't see even the simplest error… BTW: you should set one of the answer as accepted answer...

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add a placeholder for confirm password

```
NSString *postData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"FirstName=%@&LastName=%@&Email=%@&User=%@&Pass=%@&ConfirmPass=%@", _userFirstNameEntry, _userLastNameEntry, _emailEntry, _userEntry, _userPasswordEntry, _userConfirmPasswordEntry];
```